# Unable to set headers in rails integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing

I have an integration test

```
class UsersTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'get  user' do    
    get '/users/me', headers: {'Authorization' => 'tokenvalue'}    
  end
end
```

and then I have UsersController with method

```
  # GET /users/me
  def me
    puts headers
  end
```

and my output is

```
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff"}
```

so for some reason the headers are not being set,
I have also tried

```
get '/users/me', nil , headers: {'Authorization' => 'tokenvalue'}
```

or

```
get '/users/me', params: {}, headers: { HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: "token" }
```

but without any success and

```
request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = "token"
```

is not accessible in the integrationTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen you can't have total access to your `request.headers` within your integration tests but you can validate them in your tests by using the `headers` option.

I've made this workaround; I've written `index` method which is validating the `Authorization` header is set on the request, like:

```
def index
  if request.headers['Authorization'].nil?
    render json: { error: 'no auth' }, status: :unauthorized
  else
    @boxes = Box.all
  end 
end
```

And in the tests I'm validating the presence and absence of this token just accessing to the `headers` and checking the value of the `Authorization` header, then for the status, and then for the error message given in the JSON response:

```
test 'should get index if authorization is present' do
  get boxes_url, headers: { 'Authorization' => 'hallo' }
  assert_response :success
end

test 'should not get index if authorization is not present' do
  get boxes_url, headers: { 'Authorization' => nil }
  assert_response :unauthorized
  body = JSON.parse(response.body)
  assert_equal 'no auth', body['error']
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried?

`get '/users/me', nil, {'Authorization' => 'tokenvalue'}`

Comment: Yes and the output is still the same.

Comment: Just to mention, that's the old way _DEPRECATION WARNING: Using positional arguments in integration tests has been deprecated,
in favor of keyword arguments, and will be removed in Rails 5.1_.

Comment: yes, exactly I get the deprecation warning, but nevertheless it doesnt work. Is it possible that the integration tests throws away the authz header?

Comment: Do you need to access to your `request.headers` within your integration test?, do you need to validate for a token presence?

Comment: No I dont, but in the users_controller I need to validate the authz header

Comment: I've made an answer, is it what you're looking for?